# How to rebuild RPM Database

Tags: linux, database, rpm

I'm trying to rebuild the RPM DB Files to conform to the new md5sums of the files, so when the rpm is uninstalled, those files will still be removed.

I have a application that Installs with RPM, but the upgrade process doesn't use RPM's it uses patches to apply to those files, but when uninstalling using rpm -e --dbpath , the files that were patched remain. Is there anyway to rebuild the rpm db to include these new files?

Comment: http://bit.ly/xMOjHF

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. The update process should be done with RPM as well; otherwise, RPM will see the files as changed - though files should still be removed I would guess.

You could try using the code:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

But I don't know if that would fix it.

You could also try something like this to "remove" the package from the database and remove the files manually:

```
rpm -e --justdb
```

But this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yea, I've tried the rebuilddb to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve the immediate problem at hand, however to prevent these problems in the future I would recommend a custom in house repository and rebuilding your RPMs to include these files. I did this with several packages with satisfactory results.